# Sorting out unique elements from a list to a set

Tags: python, function

I was writing a function to save unique values returned by a list "list_accepted_car" to a set "unique_accepted_ant". list_car_id is list with the value ['12','18','3','7']. When i run the code i am getting error , "unhashable list ". Can anyone suggest me what is the error?

```
list_accepted_car = []        #set to store the value list_accepted_car
unique_accepted_car = set()     #set to store the value unique_accepted_car
num_accepted = 2               #predifined value for the number of cars allowed to enter
def DoIOpenTheDoor(list_car_id):  #list_ant_id is a list of cars allowed to enter
    if len(list_accepted_car) < num_accepted:
        if len(list_car_id) > 0:
            list_accepted_car.append(list_car_id[0:min(len(list_car_id),num_accepted-len(list_accepted_car))])            
    unique_accepted_list = set(list_accepted_car)
    print unique_accepted_list
    return list_accepted_car
```

Comment: unique_accepted_list = set(list_accepted_car)
print unique_accepted_list
return list_accepted_car
This part of the code should also be indented

Comment: Can you fix the indentation please? (`return` outside of `def`)

Comment: because   list_accepted_car.append(list_car_id[0:min(len(list_car_id),num_accepted-len(list_accepted_car))])  statements appends lists in list. so you can't do set operation on list of lists.

Comment: @Nuageux indentation is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that `list_car_id` looks like: `[1,2,3,4,5]`.
You add in `list_accepted_car` a sublist of `list_car_id`, so `list_accepted_car` will look like `[[1,2]]` i.e. a list of a list.
Then you should change

```
unique_accepted_list = set(list_accepted_car)
```

to

```
unique_accepted_list = set([x for y in list_accepted_car for x in y])
```

which will extract each element of the sublist and provide a flatten list. (There exists other options to flatten a list of list)

Answer (score 0):

You are saving a list of lists, which can't be converted to a set. You have to flatten it first. There are many examples of how to do it (I'll supply one using `itertools.chain` which I prefer to python's nested comprehension).

Also, as a side note, I'd make this line more readable by separating to several lines:

```
list_accepted_car.append(list_car_id[0:min(len(list_car_id),num_accepted-len(list_accepted_car))])
```

You can do:

```
from itertools import chain
# code ...
unique_accepted_list = set(chain.from_iterable(list_accepted_car))
```

The best option would be to not use a list at all here, and use a set from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Lists are not hashable objects, and only hashable objects can be members of sets. So, you can't have a set of lists. This instruction:
    list_accepted_car.append(list_car_id[0:min(len(list_car_id),num_accepted-len(list_accepted_car))])

appends a slice of `list_car_id` to `list_accepted_car`, and a slice of a list is a **list**. So in effect `list_accepted_car` becomes a list of lists, and that's why converting it to a set:

```
unique_accepted_list = set(list_accepted_car)
```

fails. Maybe what you wanted is `extend` rather than `append`? I can't say, because I don't know what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for comments. What i want to achieve is, given      list_ant_id = ['1','2','3','4','5']     and num_accepted = 2, I wan t the list_accepted_cars = ['1','2'] . Currently its giving me [['1','2'],[1] ] . The list contains the same element repeated.